# Is there a way to share a Queue between independent processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc

I am working in python 3. I want to share a Queue(s) between processes. I want the processes to be started independently on ad hoc basis and not by `Process(target=,...)`. Actually there will be a central `channel` processes and many `station` processes are to share their own `queue` with it.

The `queue` will be pushed by channel and will be popped by the stations and will contain `BitArray` objects. Also there will be a `channel queue` into which stations will push and channel will pop.

I though a `BaseManager` would be able to do so. But I can't understand how to use it from the docs.

Comment: If they are started using the `multiprocessing` module, then yes, a `Queue` can be shared.  That is its primary purpose.  If they are being started separately, then no.  Instead, you will probably want to use a TCP socket or a named pipe.

Comment: @TimRoberts There are libraries that support the use of true POSIX IPC mechanisms in Python. Queues created that way should be accessible by any process if it has the key and the permissions are set to allow it. But I agree, sockets are much cleaner.

Comment: If you're on a posix machine [this](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) library is simple and effective. I've used it when I needed shared memory backported to 3.6. The suggestion of a socket server is also quite good, and more portable.